# Find index of an array element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Suppose I have an array: `var a=[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]` If I write a[1] it returns [2,2].  But if I want to return the index of the array element  `[2,2]` like `a.indexOf([2,2])` it returns -1 which is not found.  Is there an elegant way to find the index of an array element in an array?

Comment: Since you need a custom equality, you probably want `findIndex`. Unless you want an ES3 solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.findIndex()`

```
var index = a.findIndex(function(el) {
  return el[0] == 2 && el[1] === 2
});
```

```
var index = a.findIndex(function(el) {
  return el.every(function(n) {return n === 2})
});
```